# Eclipse unable to add apache tomcat 10

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, jersey

For Jersey 3.x, I am forced to use Apache tomcat 10

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62597059/2074888

```
If you want to use Jersey 3.x with Servlets, you need to use a servlet container that implements Servlet 5 API, e.g. Tomcat 10, Jetty 11, Glassfish 6.
```

So I have installed latest eclipse

[image]

But I am not able find an option to install Apache Tomcat 10

[image]

Comment: Tomcat 10 is still an alpha version and not yet integrated in Eclipse. Neither Tomcat 10 nor Jersey 3 have released any stable versions, which limits available tool compatibility. For anything you want to place publicly this year, I'd stick with Jersey 2 and Tomcat 9 for now. Otherwise you could look for plugins that add the functionality as a preview

Answer (score 3):

Well, tomcat is not officially launched into eclipse as of May 28, 2021. But you can use it 2 ways:

**1. Download portable installer**

Tomcat 10.0 is supported in portable installer

**2. Use Eclipse Tomcat**

**Step 1:** Goto `Help` > `Eclipse Marketplace` > Search **Eclipse Tomcat** > Install it.

**Step 2:** Restart Eclipse
b. Goto `Windows` > `Preferences` > `Tomcat`

**Step 3:** Select version 9.x(+)

**Step 4:** Browse the directory where Tomcat 10 is located.

[image]

(Image for step 3 and 4)

**Step 5:** Now, *3* Tomcat icons will be visible in **Standard Toolbar**. To **start**, **stop** and **restart** use those 3 icons

[image]

(Image for Step 5)

Comment: Tomcat 10 is supported since WTP 3.20 (Eclipse 2020-12): cf. [release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.20/NewAndNoteworthy/).

Comment: There are still some quirks in the support (e.g. Tomcat 10 is classified as a Servlet 4.0 runtime), but it is usable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try installing `Eclipse Tomcat Plugin` in **Eclipse Marketplace** and then configure the path to the downloaded **Tomcat10** directory.

Comment: This question is more than 9 months old. Support for Tomcat 10 was introduced in Eclipse 2020-12 (cf. [release notes](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.20/NewAndNoteworthy/)).